# Moving data between Content databases

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint-2010

I want to move data from a contentdb to a different web app's contentdb.. Is this possible? 
Please help !

Answer (score 0):

This [MSDN post](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc287899%28v=office.14%29.aspx) might help you.